# Como gerar SQL em tabela de relacionamento sem repetir valores?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho o seguinte cenário:
Tabelas:

```
Video (id, url)
VideoCategoria (id, id_video, id_categoria)
Categoria (id, descricao)
```

Eu preciso pegar as ultimas 120 categorias que receberam videos. No mesmo cursor eu queria o seguintes campos:

```
(Video.Url, Categoria.descricao)
```

Só que não pode repetir a `url` do video, por exemplo, se um unico video entra com duas categorias diferentes então a categoria 1 e 2 estão vindo com a mesma `Url`.

Já foi dada uma solução aqui usando `cursor` e fazendo `loops` até achar outro vídeo, tentei fazer tudo no SQL, mas não estou conseguindo fazer, alguém sabe se é possível?

Eu estou usando o `id` da tabela `Video_Categoria` para pegar os registros mais novos.

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Esquema criado no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc985) como solicitado no comentário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui montar com a ajuda do Entity Framework e o resto eu mesmo terminei.

Segue a solução:

```js
select 
 v.url,
 c.id,
 c.description
 
 
  from (
select top 120 a.id_video, max(id_categoria) as id_categoria from (


SELECT  
    [Join2].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Join2].[ID_VIDEO] AS [ID_VIDEO], 
    [Join2].[ID_CATEGORIA] AS [ID_CATEGORIA]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent2].[ID_VIDEO] AS [K1], 
        MAX([Extent2].[ID_VIDEO]) AS [A1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ID_CATEGORIA] AS [K1], 
            MAX([Extent1].[ID]) AS [A1]
            FROM [VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent1]
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[ID_CATEGORIA] ) AS [GroupBy1]
        INNER JOIN [VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent2] ON ([GroupBy1].[K1] = [Extent2].[ID_CATEGORIA]) AND ([Extent2].[ID] = [GroupBy1].[A1])
        GROUP BY [Extent2].[ID_VIDEO] ) AS [GroupBy2]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent4].[ID_VIDEO] AS [ID_VIDEO], [Extent4].[ID_CATEGORIA] AS [ID_CATEGORIA]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Extent3].[ID_CATEGORIA] AS [K1], 
            MAX([Extent3].[ID]) AS [A1]
            FROM [VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent3]
            GROUP BY [Extent3].[ID_CATEGORIA] ) AS [GroupBy3]
        INNER JOIN [VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent4] ON ([GroupBy3].[K1] = [Extent4].[ID_CATEGORIA]) AND ([Extent4].[ID] = [GroupBy3].[A1]) ) AS [Join2] ON ([GroupBy2].[K1] = [Join2].[ID_VIDEO]) AND ([Join2].[ID_VIDEO] = [GroupBy2].[A1])

  ) as a


group by a.id_video
order by id_video
) as grupo

join 
[CATEGORIA] as c
on grupo.id_categoria = c.id
join 
[VIDEO] as v
on grupo.id_video = v.id
```

Answer (score 2):

você pode usar o `DISTINCT` para garantir que somente um valor será retornado.

Comment: você pode usar o [Rextester](http://rextester/runcode) ou [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para criar test case e facilitar a ajuda ;)

Answer (score 1):

Video (1, 'TestoUrl1'), (2, 'testeUrl2')
VideoCategoria(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)
Categoria(1, 'Terror'), (2, 'Ação')

Se você quer retornar a URL do Video e a Descrição da Categoria, **sempre irá** retornar URL repedidas para categorias diferentes. Pois o retorno ficaria:

```
TesteUrl1, Terror  
TesteUrl1, Ação
```

Distinct para esse caso não resolve.

A dica que dou é utilizar a URL como o nome do campo de retorno e os dados são a descrição, ficando desta maneira por exemplo:

```
TesteUrl1    TesteUrl2
Terror       ação
Ação         Terror
```

deu pra entender?

Comment: Nesse caso eu teria q ter 120 colunas, certo? Uma para cada categoria q quero.

Comment: Não, a Coluna seriam as URLs, se temos 120 categorias porém todas estão na mesma URL, então teria apenas 1 Coluna.

Comment: Por favor, faça um exemplo destas tabelas com dados ficticios neste site: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Criei e atualizei a pergunta, só não entendi como roda o sql lá, não tenho certeza se fiz certo. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc985

Comment: SqlFiddle com o seu select [sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc985/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc985/2). Utilizando o seu select no site gerou um erro falando que o campo url não existe, você chegou a testar no sql server?

Comment: O finddle deve estar errado, o sql q eu usei já está rodando já.